# MySQL Workbench Unable to Connect to Azure Databases for MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, mysql-workbench

When  trying to connect to a MySQL database in Azure I get the following error:

> ERROR 2026: SSL connection error: socket layer receive error

At first I thought it was a firewall/security issue but it appears not. The certificates are correct - and I have also tried with SSL disabled on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

[This article hints at the issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b44fe6c-18bf-4624-8d38-470846816d91/error-2026-ssl-connection-error-socket-layer-receive-error?forum=AzureDatabaseforMySQL), though it is slightly different. After updating the SQL Connector from version 6.x to 8.0.11 and workbench itself to 6.3.10 it has worked perfectly.